# R - Slider for gwindow

Tags: r

if i create a long window using gwindow (gWidgets):

> newwin <- gwindow("abc", width = 500, height = 1200)

How can i pull out a slider to slide down the window?

Comment: I don't think you add a scrollbar to a window directly - I think you add it to the `ggroup` inside it via `ggroup(cont=newwin, use.scrollwindow=T, ...)`, and when you cram enough stuff into that ggroup the scrollbar appears?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee : can you make your comment an answer so it can be accepted by silverspoon?

Comment: Sure (I put that down as a hunch - wasn't sure it'd work, hence left it as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a scrollbar to a window directly.

However, you *can* add a scrollbar to a `ggroup` with the `use.scrollwindow` argument:

```
win <- gwindow('abc', width=500, height=1200)
g   <- ggroup(cont=win, use.scrollwindow=T, horizontal=F, ... )
```

On my platform, linux, using gWidgetsGtk2 as the base toolkit, the scrollbar doesn't appear immediately. I assume that if you cram that `ggroup` with enough widgets, the scrollbar will automagically appear.

Perhaps in tcltk or backends to gwidgets the scrollbar will appear straight away, but I get the feeling it'll just appear as needed (which makes sense).

Comment: As much as the underlying toolkit allows, the scrollbars appear when needed. There isn't good standardization here. RGtk2 works best. The tcltk bit is a big hack, and the Qt implementation requires some care.